# Problem when adding React Navigation Drawer - TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(..)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I'm having a problem when adding a Drawer Navigator, with the 'react navigation' package.

What I have already tried:

1. Tripled checked the packages listed on the documentation of React Navigation
2. Re-created the project from scratch
3. Installed the react native reanimated package acording to the docs on its page.
4. Cleared the cache from npm and react-native.
5. Tried only with Stack Navigator, it works, the problem only appears when using Drawer Navigator

The error is the following: `ERROR Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.`

Answer (score 0):

following the steps in the [official react-native-animation installation guide](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/) one by one helped me to solve the problem

Comment: It didn't work, I checked the React Native's issues section on GitHub, and it seems a lot of people is facing the same problem with new projects. There isn't a clear solution yet